# OCaml return value in if statement nested in loop

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to return a value if something occurs when iterating through a list. Is it possible to return a string if X happens when iterating through the list, otherwise return another string if it never happens?

```
let f elem =
  if not String.contains str elem then "false" in
List.iter f alphlist;

"true";
```

This is not working in my implemented method sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCaml is a functional language, so you pretty much need to concentrate on the values returned by functions. There are ways to return different values in exceptional cases, but (IMHO) the best way to learn is to start just with ordinary old nested function calls.

`List.iter` always returns the same value: `()`, which is known as `unit`.

For this reason, the expression `List.iter f alphlist` will also always return `()` no matter what `f` does.

There is another kind of list-handling function that works by maintaining a value across all the calls and returning that value at the end. It's called a fold.

So, if you want to compute some value that's a kind of summary of what it saw in all of the string lists in `alphlist`, you should probably be using a fold, say `List.fold_left`.

Here is a function `any_has_7` that determines whether any one of the specified lists contains the integer 7:

```
let any_has_7 lists =
    let has_7 sofar list =
        sofar || List.mem 7 list
    in
    List.fold_left has_7 false lists
```

Here's how it looks when you run it:

```
# any_has_7 [[1;2]; [3;4]];;
- : bool = false
# any_has_7 [[1;2]; [5;7]; [8;9]];;
- : bool = true
```

In other words, this function does something a lot like what you're asking for. It returns `true` when one or more of the lists contains a certain value, and `false` when none of them contains the value.

I hope this helps.